# How to delay Gmail send of messages to allow 'undo send' feature?

Tags: gmail

I hear that Gmail has ability to delay sending emails for up to 30 seconds so that you can undo the send, but I am unable to locate the setting.

Where does this setting exist in Gmail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn this on in the Settings (gear icon), in the `General` tab, see `Undo Send:` field which can be set at `Send Cancellation Period` to 5, 10, 20, or 30 `Seconds`:

[image]

---

Old solution that no longer is visible, replaced by above solution:

> It is in the 'Labs' section of settings, you have to enable this experimental feature.  Search for 'undo send' to find it.  You can then configure the delay of send from 5 up to 30 seconds in the General tab of your settings.  It defaults to 10 seconds.

Comment: This feature has graduated from Labs and is now available on the "General" tab in Settings.

Comment: Labs [is deprecated](https://support.google.com/a/answer/117099?hl=en).

Answer (score 10):

> If you make a typo or regret sending a message, you can undo the
>   action by enabling "Undo send." This setting gives you the option to
>   take back a message you just sent.
>
> To enable Undo Send:
>
> - Click the gear in the top right [image: Gear]
> - Select **Settings**.
> - Scroll down to "Undo Send" and click **Enable**.
> - Set the cancellation period (the amount of time you have to decide if you want to unsend an email).
> - Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page. If you had Undo Send turned on in Gmail Labs, your Undo Send setting will be on by
>     default.
>
> **Note:** To give you time to undo, Gmail delays sending the message for a few seconds. So if you don't select "Undo" within the time
>   limit, your message will be sent. "Undo send" may not work if you
>   experience connection issues.

Taken from [this Google Support article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1284885?hl=en).

Comment: ...or just click [https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general) right away.